# Clickable absolute local file link in VS Code Markdown Preview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

How can I add a link to my markdown file that will display a clickable link in VS Code Markdown Preview that opens a local file using an absolute file path?

I tried the 5 variations shown below...

- The 1st and 2nd lines aren't clickable at all
- The 3rd line attempts to open `C:\temp\C:\temp\test_file.txt` and fails
- The 4th line doesn't do anything when I click it
- The 5th line works but this uses a relative path. I need to use an absolute path

```markdown
[test_file](file:///C:/temp/test_file.txt)

[test_file](/C:/temp/test_file.txt)

<a href = "file:///C:/temp/test_file.txt"> test_file </a>

[test_file](./test_file.txt)

[test_file](<file:///C:/temp/test_file.txt>)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change file paths to make links to local files work in VSCode Markdown](/q/74157383/4518341)

Comment: I saw that before posting but the answer just doesn't work for me. It appears as unclickable plaintext just like the first example in my question, and additionally when I autoformat the file the `<>` symbols disappear making it identical to my first example. But I will add it to the question just for the sake of completeness

Comment: It is odd that in the markdown file you can alt-click on a file like `file:///C:/temp/test_file.txt` and it opens properly, but when previewed (as a link) vscode can't parse the link at all?!

Answer (score 0):

I found a GitHub feature request for this so it seems like the answer for now is "you can't"

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182870

Comment: And there are more issues asking for absolute links, I think you are limited to relative links.  So from your workspace to the `temp` folder, which you can find by copying the test file and dropping it into the markdown file with `Shift` held down.  You might end up with something like this `[test_file](../../../../temp/test_file.txt)` - awful but it works.  As long as it is for use on your fileSystem only.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/164650